# get unique ID for Win32 DLL instance?

Tags: winapi, dll

Is there a simple way to get a unique ID for the specific DLL instance some C/C++ code is currently running in? Maybe &DllMain? But that function is optional.

Comment: what you mean under *unique id* ? for what this need - how you plan use it ?

Comment: I'm writing a plugin dll that registers a window class name, but I need a different window class name for each plugin instance.

Comment: but in every process - will be only single your dll. and different processes not conflict here

Comment: you of course can use say address of dll begin in memory (`&__ImageBase`) as part of class name, but i simply not think that this need. are you have **multiple** self dll in process ? are you got error, that class already registered under some condition ?

Comment: hmm, yeah, maybe it's sufficient to define the window class name on a per DLL basis.

Comment: probably yes, every plugin can have static unique name for class

Comment: [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873)

Comment: Then this is the issue: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/52ba8c7f07574d56955099179f35569e07e2001c/src/win32_init.c#L351 GLFW is using a NULL argument for GetModuleHandleW. Looks like I need to rewrite this to support glfwInit(HINSTANCE) and call it from DllMain

Comment: @user1050755 `GetModuleHandleW(NULL)` returns the `HINSTANCE` of the EXE that created the calling process. There is no call to `RegisterClass()` in that `win32_init.c` file, so where is that call being made exactly? Which `HINSTANCE` is being used to register `_GLFW_WNDCLASSNAME`? The calls to `RegisterClass()` and `CreateWindowEx()` need to use the same `HINSTANCE`, unless the class is registered globally.

Comment: https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/52ba8c7f07574d56955099179f35569e07e2001c/src/win32_window.c#L1374

Comment: *"Looks like I need \[...\] glfwInit(HINSTANCE)"* - No, not really. Just [get the `HINSTANCE` of the calling module](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041025-00/?p=37483). Use `GetModuleHandleExW` instead, if you need a portable solution. *"call it from DllMain"* - [No](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

Answer (score 3):

> I'm writing a plugin dll that registers a window class name, but I need a different window class name for each plugin instance

No, you don't. DLLs don't have unique IDs, but they do have unique `HINSTANCE`s. Multiple DLLs can register the *same* class name, but still do *different* things. The classes are differentiated by the `HINSTANCE` that registers/creates them at runtime.

Refer to this for more info:

[What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873)

> When it comes time to create a window, each module then passes its own HINSTANCE when creating the window, and the window manager uses the combination of the instance handle and the class name to look up the class.
>
> CreateWindow("MyClass", ..., hinstA, ...); // creates class 6
> CreateWindow("MyClass", ..., hinstB, ...); // creates class 7
> CreateWindow("MyClass", ..., hinstC, ...); // fails
>
> **This is why it is okay if multiple DLLs all register a class called “MyClass”; the instance handle is used to tell them apart.**